# Using Scala macro to generate function with returned value depending on argument values

Tags: scala, macros, metaprogramming

I want to write a function that gets 1 argument (lets call it arg: _), and returns Option[Tuple2] such that if arg has a field that extends MyMarkerTrait the returned tuple will be (field_name, field_value): Tuple2[String, MyMarkerTrait].

This is easy with reflection, but I want to do it at compile time using macros.

In a macro, I'd also want to return not only Tuple2[String, MyMarkerTrait], but rather the full type of arg as the second element. So if arg is:
val arg: MyType with MyMarkerTrait
the function generated by my macro should return 
Tuple2[String, MyType with MyMarkerTrait]

Comment: This is definitely possible, but I'm not sure you're going to find somebody to write the whole thing for you from scratch.

Comment: @TravisBrown I just need some pointers. Things like what I should google. I'm not new to scala, but I am new to macros. I couldn't figure out how to iterate over the argument fields and access the type of each field (MyType with MyMarkerTrait) and its value. Anything will be highly appriciated, reading list of blogs, code examples, links to projects with good readble code that use macros so I can learn from. I'm not looking for someone to write it for me, but much rather get help to how to learn it, since I'm a bit lost.

Comment: It'd help if you could write some example code that highlights a call to your macro + shows desired output.